# Place the 15 buttons on rows of columns or on columns of rows fashion

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't figure out how to do it like this. Everything I try messes it up

You will need to set mainAxisAlignment and CrossAxisAlignment arguments

[image]

Comment: I suggest you using GridView instead of using nested row and column.

Comment: Please show us the code your are using. We can't help you otherwise. Also, add more detail to your descrpition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("data"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `GridView.count` like code below. this way has less repeated code and more
flexible:

```
class Test1 extends StatelessWidget {
  List<ButtonWidget> list = [
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
      onPressed: (){//do something
},
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
    ButtonWidget(
      text: 'test',
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: GridView.count(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        children: List.generate(list.length, (index) => list[index]),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function onPressed;
  ButtonWidget({@required this.text, this.onPressed});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Text(text),
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```